# Why joyGetPos works, and joyGetPosEx does not?

Tags: c++, windows

Currently writing a small program using a joystick, I struggle to understand why the joyGetPos() works, while joyGetPosEx() does not.

I did some basic program using C++, and it's my first project using a joystick.

Platform: windows 7 64 bit

Joystick: http://www.thrustmaster.com/en_UK/products/hotas-cougar

Doc on the joystick functions: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757121(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Code for JOYINFO

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    while ( true )
    {
        unsigned int num_dev = joyGetNumDevs();

        if ( 0 == num_dev )
        {
            std::cout << "[ERROR ] num_dev == 0" << std::endl;
        }

        /* JOYINFO */

        // retreiving the joystick values
        JOYINFO joyinfo;
        MMRESULT joygetpos_result = joyGetPos( JOYSTICKID1, &joyinfo );

        // if tested, joygetpos_result  does not produce any error

        // values change when playing with the stick
        std::cout << "joinfo.wXpos = " << joinfo.wXpos << std::endl;
        std::cout << "joinfo.wYpos = " << joinfo.wYpos << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This version is quite well, but the big grey hat and 4 buttons out of 18 do not work.

Code for JOYINFOEX

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    while ( true )
    {
        unsigned int num_dev = joyGetNumDevs();

        if ( 0 == num_dev )
        {
            std::cout << "[ERROR ] num_dev == 0" << std::endl;
        }


        /* JOYINFOEX */
        // retreiving the joystick values
        JOYINFOEX joyinfoex;
        MMRESULT joygetposex_result = joyGetPosEx( JOYSTICKID1, &joyinfoex);


        // error always produced
        if ( joygetposex_result == JOYERR_PARMS)
        {
            std::cout << "[ERROR ] JOYERR_PARMS" << std::endl;
        }

        // values does not change when playing with the stick
        std::cout << "joinfoex.dwXpos = " << joinfoex.dwXpos << std::endl;
        std::cout << "joinfoex.dwYpos = " << joinfoex.dwYpos << std::endl;

}
```

This second version is always producing the JOYERR_PARMS error. I tried to change the JOYSTICKID1 from 1 to 15, but without any success. I think I am not using correctly the windows functions, but unfortunately I am not able to understand the correct way to use it.

Did you face the same problem? Am I using the good API to use such joystick ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: RTFM: "You must set the dwSize and dwFlags members or joyGetPosEx will fail."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MSDN page on joyGetPosEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Pointer to a JOYINFOEX structure that contains extended position information and button status of the joystick. You must set the dwSize and dwFlags members or joyGetPosEx will fail.

You will need to populate your variable joyinfoex with the size and flags.

```
joyinfoex.dwSize = sizeof(joyinfoex);
joyinfoex.dwFlags = JOY_RETURNALL;
```

Comment: Oh okay okay. Thanks, it looks astonishingly clear right now but this part of the documentation was terribly obscure for me! I was not used to set "what I want" into one object returned by a function. Thanks again.

Comment: You'll have to get used to it - a lot of the WinAPI is like this. Just always read the docs for every WinAPI function carefully without making assumptions.